# Cropping with paperclip not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am trying to implement the cropping with `paperclip` and `jcrop` but nothing is happend with the uploaded image.

I am trying with the following way.
Here is my modal code ..................

```
attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => {:big => "200>x200"},
    :convert_options => {:blurred_card => "-blur 0x8"}, 
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/user_albums/:id/:style.:extension",
    :processors => [:cropper],
    :url => "/system/user_albums/:id/:style.:extension",
        :default_url => "/images/sss.png"
    after_update :reprocess_picture, :if => :cropping?

  def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
  end

  def picture_geometry(style = :original)
    @geometry ||= {}
    @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(picture.path(style))
  end

  private

  def reprocess_picture
    picture.reprocess!
  end
```

Processor code

```
module Paperclip  
  class Cropper < Thumbnail  
    def transformation_command  
      if crop_command
        original_command = super
        if original_command.include?('-crop')
          original_command.delete_at(super.index('-crop') + 1)
          original_command.delete_at(super.index('-crop'))
        end
        crop_command + original_command
      else  
        super  
      end  
    end  

    def crop_command  
      target = @attachment.instance  
      if target.cropping?
        ["-crop", "#{target.crop_w}x#{target.crop_h}+#{target.crop_x}+#{target.crop_y}"]
      end  
    end  
  end  
end
```

Do we need to make the columns in database for crop related like the below

`:crop_x`, `:crop_y`, `:crop_w`, `:crop_h`

Comment: Do we need to add the fields :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h in database or not need?

Comment: no need to add in database since you only need them for the crop and that they are accessible from your model.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `attr_accessible` in your model somewhere. This creates a whitelists of the attributes you can set using update_attributes. Your crop fields are not listed, so they can't be set using update_attributes.

The solution is to add the following in your model:

```
  attr_accessible :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
```

Which will enable the following will work:

```
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Alternately, you can manually set the attributes

```
  @user.crop_x = x
  @user.crop_y = y
  @user.crop_w = w
  @user.crop_h = h
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use # instead of > as a parameter:

> has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :big=> "200#x200" }